# Python Regex to get numbers inside and outside brackets after key word

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex function to get the numbers after Operating profit/(loss) **keyword** i.e  1,644 193 1,837 1,280 (263) 1,017 (see text below); I have tried a number of regex functions but they are not working.

The text looks like this:

> Continuing operations Revenue 2 57,491 – 57,491 55,917 – 55,917 Cost of sales (54,092) (49) (54,141) (52,899) (116) (53,015) Gross profit/(loss) 3,399 (49) 3,350 3,018 (116) 2,902 Administrative expenses Profits/(losses) arising on property-related items (1,786) 31 153 89 (1,633) 120 (1,734) (4) (261) 114 (1,995) 110 Operating profit/(loss) 1,644 193 1,837 1,280 (263) 1,017 Share of post-tax profits/(losses) of joint ventures and associates Finance income Finance costs 13 5 5 (6) 98 (593) – – (38) (6) 98 (631) (30) 109 (630) (77) – (244) (107) 109 (874) Profit/(loss) before tax 1,143 155 1,298 729 (584) 145 Taxation 6 (286) (20) (306) (185) 98 (87) Profit/(loss) for the year from continuing operations 857 135 992 544 (486) 58 Discontinued operations Profit/(loss) for the year from discontinued operations 7 – 216 216 (37) (75) (112) Profit/(loss) for the year 857 351 1,208 507 (561) (54)

Comment: Please share your current regex and what is the expected result. Probably, you need to escape brackets.

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.

Comment: I used this to get numbers between key wordsOperating profit/(loss)  and Share but l want a one liner to just get numbers after Operating profit/(loss) 
 re.findall(r'Operating profit/(loss)\s*(.*?) Share',data_wanted_text)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `re.findall` here:

```
inp = "Continuing operations Revenue 2 57,491 – 57,491 55,917 – 55,917 Cost of sales (54,092) (49) (54,141) (52,899) (116) (53,015) Gross profit/(loss) 3,399 (49) 3,350 3,018 (116) 2,902 Administrative expenses Profits/(losses) arising on property-related items (1,786) 31 153 89 (1,633) 120 (1,734) (4) (261) 114 (1,995) 110 Operating profit/(loss) 1,644 193 1,837 1,280 (263) 1,017 Share of post-tax profits/(losses) of joint ventures and associates Finance income Finance costs 13 5 5 (6) 98 (593) – – (38) (6) 98 (631) (30) 109 (630) (77) – (244) (107) 109 (874) Profit/(loss) before tax 1,143 155 1,298 729 (584) 145 Taxation 6 (286) (20) (306) (185) 98 (87) Profit/(loss) for the year from continuing operations 857 135 992 544 (486) 58 Discontinued operations Profit/(loss) for the year from discontinued operations 7 – 216 216 (37) (75) (112) Profit/(loss) for the year 857 351 1,208 507 (561) (54)"
matches = re.findall(r'Operating profit/\(loss\)\s+([0-9,() ]+)\s+', inp)
print(matches[0])
```

This prints:

```
1,644 193 1,837 1,280 (263) 1,017
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for this!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
"Operating profit\/\(loss\) ([0-9, ()]*)"
```

I suggest using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to find the right regex for you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this: (Using Group)**

```
import re

string="Continuing operations Revenue 2 57,491 – 57,491 55,917 – 55,917 Cost of sales (54,092) (49) (54,141) (52,899) (116) (53,015) Gross profit/(loss) 3,399 (49) 3,350 3,018 (116) 2,902 Administrative expenses Profits/(losses) arising on property-related items (1,786) 31 153 89 (1,633) 120 (1,734) (4) (261) 114 (1,995) 110 Operating profit/(loss) 1,644 193 1,837 1,280 (263) 1,017 Share of post-tax profits/(losses) of joint ventures and associates Finance income Finance costs 13 5 5 (6) 98 (593) – – (38) (6) 98 (631) (30) 109 (630) (77) – (244) (107) 109 (874) Profit/(loss) before tax 1,143 155 1,298 729 (584) 145 Taxation 6 (286) (20) (306) (185) 98 (87) Profit/(loss) for the year from continuing operations 857 135 992 544 (486) 58 Discontinued operations Profit/(loss) for the year from discontinued operations 7 – 216 216 (37) (75) (112) Profit/(loss) for the year 857 351 1,208 507 (561) (54)"

s=re.search('Operating profit\/\(loss\) ([0-9, ()]*)',string)    
answer=s.group(1)
print answer
```

**This will print the output as follows:**

```
1,644 193 1,837 1,280 (263) 1,017
```

Kindly check the code in [LINK](https://regex101.com/r/HijebJ/1).